# Is there a java program to check whether 2 combined sentences makes sense?

Tags: java

Hi I have search around the web but found no answers. Maybe the thing that I am finding is not possible or make any sense.

I am currently trying to come up with an algorithm and searching for one too how a java program can check whether 2 or more sentences when combined are making any sense.

For example like Maths problem sums for primary schools. I want to be able to generate many same type of questions but with different parameters like the name or object in the questions can be set differently and dynamically.

Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Define "makes sense"... The sentence "purple goat grape washing" makes sense, it's entirely subjective.

Comment: If you're talking about human language - forget it, it's too hard. You might be able to generate single human-sounding sentences that sound convincingly human-like if you have enough data (lots of samples). OTOH, filling sentence templates with data should be much easier.

Comment: Colourless green ideas sleep furiously.

Comment: It seems we think alike Jan Dvorak.

Comment: I suspect it would be similar to how a compiler parser code, you would need to take into account everything for correct grammar. As the others have pointed out though, that still doesn't mean it's going to make any sense. You would need a lot of information on word relationships, etc.

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments and sharing of thoughts. I really thought the same as all of you. Its hard. I agree. :)

Comment: No worries rushh05, it's the kind of question for a Phd. You could be old and grey strolling around on your zimmer frame before you found an answer for this one.

Comment: Just peruse StackOverflow.  Lots of examples of sentences that don't make sense to me but apparently do make sense to others.  :-)

Comment: I think its nonsense to close this topic. I find it so funny. There are so many other question in Stackoverflow where people ask for comments and the topics remains open. Contradicting people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Whether a sentence "makes sense" is an extremely difficult problem and probably requires [strong AI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_AI), which is still sci-fi for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Yeah I agree too. Thanks chrylis.